# Slicing and for loops

Tags: python, list, tuples, string-formatting

Firstly, I have <48 hours hands-on-keyboard learning Python over the last week.

I searched for similar questions, and they exist, but I'm looking for a solution that introtopython.org assumes I know based on where I am in the course. (Meaning no f-strings, no conditional expressions.)

*Print out a series of sentences, "A judge can give a gymnast _ points." Don't worry if your first sentence is grammatically incorrect, but bonus points if you can figure it out with a slice.*

My first attempt code:

```py
# A gymnast can earn a score between 1 and 10 from each judge; nothing lower,
# nothing higher. All scores are integer values; there are no decimal scores
# from a single judge.

pscores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
onepoint = pscores[:1]
for pscore in onepoint:
    print("\nA judge can give a gymnast ",str(onepoint)," point.")
print("A judge can give a gymnast %d points." % (pscores[1]))
print("A judge can give a gymnast %d points." % (pscores[2]))
print("A judge can give a gymnast %d points." % (pscores[3]))
print("A judge can give a gymnast %d points." % (pscores[4]))
print("A judge can give a gymnast %d points." % (pscores[5]))
print("A judge can give a gymnast %d points." % (pscores[6]))
print("A judge can give a gymnast %d points." % (pscores[7]))
print("A judge can give a gymnast %d points." % (pscores[8]))
print("A judge can give a gymnast %d points.\n" % (pscores[9]))
```

Output:

```
A judge can give a gymnast  [1]  point.
A judge can give a gymnast 2 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 3 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 4 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 5 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 6 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 7 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 8 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 9 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 10 points.
```

Super close. I can't figure out how to get the first printed line to display with the %d placeholder, without brackets. Also, I had a **morepoints** var in there when I was trying to figure out scores 2-10 in a for loop, but I couldn't get it to work (*morepoints = pscores[1:]*)

I feel like I'm on the cusp of understanding how to do what I want without f-strings or conditional expressions (since I don't know how to use those yet).

Is it me, or is it the particular website I'm using giving me a shot to figure it out on my own based on what I've learned about lists and tuples?

EDIT: While I could get rid of the for loop I currently have and replace it with a line similar to the last 9, I'm trying to figure out how to condense all of this with slices and loops.

Comment: `print("A judge can give a gymnast %d point." % (pscores[0]))`?

Comment: Array indices start at 0, so `pscores[0]` is valid python and will get you the first element.

Comment: Apologies - I threw an edit at the bottom. I'm trying to figure out how to do this with slices and loops instead of 10 lines just printing it with placeholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slice is always a list, even when it is only one element.  So the variable `onepoint` in your code is the list containing the very first element in `pscores`.

in order to get the first element and not the list you can either grab the first index of `pscores` or `onepoint`.

```
score = pscores[0]  # this
scrore = onepoint[0]  # or this
print("\nA judge can give a gymnast ",str(score)," point.")
```

The reason why your for loop isn't working is because your iterator variable is `pscore` but the variable you convert to a string is `onepoint`.  So this would also work:

```
for pscore in onepoint:
    print("\nA judge can give a gymnast ",str(pscore)," point.")
```

If the goal is to use slices I think they probably mean slices of the string, the three lines below alone will get the results:

```
text = "A judge can give a gymnast points."

for pscore in range(1,11):
    print(text[:-8], pscore, text[-7:])
```